# Makefile missing *** separator. Stop

Tags: c++, makefile

Hi I've been trying to compile my code using a makefile but it keeps giving me the `missing *** separator. Stop` error. I made sure that after every line where I do a command I press tab. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

```
output: main.o funcs.o
  g++ main.o -o main.o funcs.o -o output
  
main.o: main.cpp
  g++ -c main.cpp

funcs.o: funcs.cpp classes.hpp
  g++ -c funcs.cpp

clean:
  rm *.o output
```

Comment: are you sure you have tabs not spaces? Certainly the code you have posted here has spaces, I recommend using an editor with a visible whitespace option

Comment: Try opening it in an editor that turns on visible whitespace, which should make any whitespace problems obvious.

Comment: Try to erase all but a pair of lines e.g. lines 1 and 2, or lines 4 and 5, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the advice. My text editor when I pressed tab was not actually giving me a tab